# Why I am getting this error using the .length property in javascript array?

Tags: javascript

```
function openOrSenior(data){
 //console.log(data.length); 
 //console.log((data[0]).length);

  for (var i=1; i<=(data.length); i++){

    for (var j=0; j<(data[j].length); j++){ // GETTING THIS CONSOLE ERROR : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

      console.log(data[j].length);
      console.log(data[j]);
      console.log(data);

    } 

  }
  return (data);
}

openOrSenior([[45, 12],[55,21]]);
```

Javascript newbie here. Why i am getting this error?

```
  for (var j=0; j<(data[j].length); j++){//codes...} // GETTING THIS CONSOLE ERROR : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Whereas the codes within that for loop works just fine :

```
  console.log(data[j].length);
  console.log(data[j]);
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: change `i<=` to `i<` ... because for example if an array is length 1 it only has `array[0]` not `array[1]` - you did it right with for j loop

Comment: usually you want `for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`

Comment: Also I see you referencing it by `data[j]` if you want the actual value inside the cell you might use `data[i][j]` because using `j` as index in `data` inside the second loop will lead to a lot of `undefined` errors, because i is the length of the whole array, and j is the length of every array inside that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is with the first loop where `i` should start from `0` and secondly in the second loop it should be `j < data[i].length` and not j itself as eventually j will increase and will go out of bound and hence the undefined exception that you are facing. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
  for (var i = 1; i < (data.length); i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (data[i].length); j++) {
      console.log(data[j].length);
      console.log(data[j]);
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
  return (data);
}

openOrSenior([
  [45, 12],
  [55, 21]
]);
```

**Needs to correct j loop iteration like for (var j = 0; j < (data[i].length); j++)**, You're having issue because when j loop is in the action after 2 iteration it has no value.